# Add custom field in wp_login_form()

Tags: wp-login-form

I am using wp_login_form() to display my custom login form..

```
  $args = array(
    'echo'           => false,
    'redirect' => ( is_ssl() ? $redirect : $redirect ) . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
    'form_id'        => 'loginform',
    'label_username' => __( 'Username' ),
    'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
    'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
    'label_log_in'   => __( 'Log In' ),
    'id_username'    => 'user_login',
    'id_password'    => 'user_pass',
    'id_remember'    => 'rememberme',
    'id_submit'      => 'wp-submit',
    'remember'       => true,
    'value_username' => '',
    'value_remember' => false

);

$form_ret .= wp_login_form( $args );
```

in the form, I need to put some additional text or note above the submit button.

I tried this one..

```
add_action('login_form','my_added_login_field');
function my_added_login_field(){
    //Output your HTML

    ?>
    <p>You can type a little note to those logging in here.</p>

    <?php
}
```

but it seems not working... can you please help me about this?

Comment: It works fine when I try it. Where did you put this code?

Comment: Please work on your code formatting. On smaller screens your code is out of  bounds, which makes it unreadable